# ajax cart yii2 реализация

Tags: yii2

Сейчас хочу сделать корзину , и стоит вопрос о концепции реализации ( есть уже готовые решения, но хочется практики)

Есть некая карточка товара с кнопкой купить, при нажатии, товар аяксом добавляется в корзину.

В хедере есть превью корзины ( как на опенкарте )[image: Типа такой]
вот собственно вопрос.
как правильно это сделать?
я вижу это так 
1) 
   1.1)обычный js код с аяксом, который посылает запрос в соответсвующий метод
   1.2) Или форма на pjax делающая собвстенно аналогичные действия
ну и что то возвращаем, и т.п

2) Вопрос с превью корзины, как ее правильно реализовать и связать обновление ее с событием добавление товара
Я думаю реализовать ее через виджет, правильно ли это?

Как правильно делать ?
Буду признателен за разьяснения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе можно пойти любым путем, которые вы описали.
Раз уж делаете через виджет, предложу вот так:

В виджете создаете экшн, который с помощью renderAjax возвращает корзину. Далее с помощью pjax добавляете/удаляете позиции и по завершению этого действия запрашиваете у виджета пересчитанную корзину. Например:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function(e) {
    //как-то проверяем, что это нужное именно нам событие, а не какое-то другое
  if (e.target.id === 'response-cart-change-action'){
  $.pjax({
    url: '/cart/get-cart', 
    container: '#user-cart-container', 
    timeout: 0, 
    push: false, 
    scrollTo: false,
    type: 'post'
   })
   }
  });
```